# Pointer arithmetic and portability

Tags: c++, pointers, embedded, pointer-arithmetic

I'm writing an application and I had to do some pointers arithmetic. However this application will be running on different architecture! I was not really sure if this would be problematic but after reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6262/Pointer-Arithmetic-and-Portable-Code), I thought that I must change it.

Here was my original code that I didn't like much:

```
class Frame{
  /* ... */
protected:
  const u_char* const m_pLayerHeader; // Where header of this layer starts
  int m_iHeaderLength;                // Length of the header of this layer
  int m_iFrameLength;                 // Header + payloads length
};

/**
 * Get the pointer to the payload of the current layer
 * @return A pointer to the payload of the current layer
 */
const u_char* Frame::getPayload() const
{
  // FIXME : Pointer arithmetic, portability!
  return m_pLayerHeader + m_iHeaderLength;
}
```

Pretty bad isn't it! Adding an `int` value to a `u_char` pointer! But then I changed to this:

```
const u_char* Frame::getPayload() const
{
  return &m_pLayerHeader[m_iHeaderLength];
}
```

I think now, the compiler is able to say how much to jump! Right? Is the operation `[]` on array considered as pointer arithmetic? Does it fix the portability problem?

Comment: Could you explain your problem in more detail? Both expressions will always return the same result. The only thing you must be sure about is what m_iHeaderLength means. As long as that's chars, u_chars or bytes, your code should work.

Comment: The problem is on the size of the u_char that can change on different architecture. I'm mostly affraid if I do "m_pLayerHeader + 1" I go two cells further or an half cell in the u_char array depending on the platform ...

Comment: You'll go sizeof(u_char) bytes... And if so worried maybe use more standard type (uint8_t) ?

Comment: sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1, as is sizeof(unsigned char) and sizeof(signed char). I expect u_char to be a typedef for unsigned char, since AFAIK u_char is not a standard type. Then it would be safe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`p + i` and `&p[i]` are synonyms when `p` is a pointer and `i` a value of integral type. So much that you can even write `&i[p]` and it's still valid (just as you can write `i + p`).

The portability issue in the example you link was coming from `sizeof(int)` varying across platforms. Your code is just fine, assuming `m_iHeaderLength` is the number of `u_char`s you want to skip.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are advancing the m_pLayerHeader by m_iHeaderLength u_chars. As long as whatever wrote the data you are pointing into has the same size for u_char, and i_HeaderLength is the number of u_chars in the header area you are safe.

But if `m_iHeaderLength` is really referring to bytes, and not u_chars, then you may have a problem if `m_iHeaderLength` is supposed to advance the pointer past other types than char.

Say you are sending data from a 16-bit system to a 32-bit system, your header area is defined like this

```
struct Header {
    int something;
    int somethingElse;
};
```

Assume that is only part of the total message defined by the struct Frame.

On the 32-bit machine you write the data out to a port that the 16-bit machine will read from.

```
port->write(myPacket, sizeof(Frame));
```

On the 16-bit machine you have the same Header definition, and try to read the information.

```
port->read(packetBuffer, sizeof(Frame));
```

You are already in trouble because you've tried to read twice the amount of data the sender wrote. The size of int on the 16-bit machine doing the reading is two, and the size of the header is four. But the header size was eight on the sending machine, two ints of four bytes each.

Now you attempt to advance your pointer

```
m_iHeaderLength = sizeof(Header);
...
packetBuffer += m_iHeaderLength;
```

`packetBuffer` will still be pointing into the data which was in the header in the frame sent from the originator.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why there would be a problem if m_iHeaderLength referred to the number of bytes?

Answer (score 0):

*If* there is a portability problem, then no, that wouldn't fix it. `m_pLayerHeader + m_iHeaderLength` and `&m_pLayerHeader[m_iHeaderLength]` are completely equivalent (in this case).

Comment: In what case are the two *not* equivalent?

Comment: m_pLayerHeader + 1 does it go the next cell in the u_char array on all architecture?

Comment: @avip if it's a user defined type with overloaded `operator[]` and `operator+`.

Comment: Ah, OK :-). Or if #define + -